# Couchdb retrieving documents in array

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

The following document is a small example which is stored in CouchDB.

```
{
  "_id": "Test4",
  "referenceName": "refA",
  "positions": {
      "A": 422,
      "B": 5442
  },


  "properties": [
      {
          "tId": "ARQ3TPR7",
          "pos": 4609,
          "zIds": [
              "z0003674",
              "z0008150",
              "z0016020",
              "z0016021"
          ]
      }
  ],
  ...
}
```

The below map function does not work and I don't know how to fix it. I got `Error: compilation_error Expression does not eval to a function`. I would like to retrieve `_id`, `referenceName` and `positions`.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/doc",
  "views": {
    "by_zIds": {
      "map": "function(doc) {
                for (var i in properties {
                  var d = doc.properties[i];
                  for (var x in d.zIds){
                    emit(d.zIds[x], doc);
                  }
                }
              }"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

How is it possible to fix the above map function in order to use the view like `/dbname/_design/doc/_view/by_zIds?key="z0016021"`?

Comment: Please provide more information about how your map function doesn't work. What result would you like to see? What does actually happen?

Comment: I got `Error: compilation_error Expression does not eval to a function`. I would like only retrieve `_id, referenceName and positions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way, but I am not sure whether it is the best way

```
function(doc) {
    for (var i in doc.properties) {
        for (var x in doc.properties[i].zIds) {
            emit(doc.properties[i].zIds[x], doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to improve?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `)` missing after `properties` in your map function. There might be other typos. I would suggest that you write your map functions in an editor with syntax highlighting and them  locally to catch those kinds of errors early.

EDIT: There are several other problems with your map function, all of which can be found with unit testing and/or debugging. This should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
function(doc) {
    for (var d in doc.properties) {
        for (var x in d.zIds) {
            emit(x, doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there was a `)` missing, but the view does not find anything. What could be the reason?

Comment: @user977828: I edited the question in response to your question

Comment: Thank you. Still does not find anything. What is the best way to debugging the map functions?